# How to fix a position of a particular section for some time being?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to understand how we can fix the position of the particular section for time being just like in the below example.

https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch?option.watch_cases=MWT32LL/A&option.watch_bands=MXP02AM/A&preSelect=false&product=Z0YQ&step=detail#

In the above link, the apple watch product is fixed while the right content moves to some extent, and then the whole page moves.

I tried working on this by making the left side fixed by providing class **sticky-top**

```
<h1 class="poolProductTitle text-center">Browse Premium Products</h1>
<section class="mainContainer ">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-left left sticky-top">
         <h3 class="font-weight-normal mb-3 filterTitle">Filters </h3>
         <!-- gender :radio -->
         <div id="gender">
            <h5 class="font-weight-normal mb-3">Gender </h5>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2">
               <input type="radio" id="male" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
               <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="male">men</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2">
               <input type="radio" id="female" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
               <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="female">women</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio mb-2">
               <input type="radio" id="unisex" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
               <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="unisex">unisex</label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <!-- brand :checkbox  -->
         <div id="gender">
            <h5 class="font-weight-normal mb-3">Brand </h5>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="rolex">
               <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="rolex">rolex</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="nike">
               <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="nike">nike</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="adidas">
               <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="adidas">adidas</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="dell">
               <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="dell">dell</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="apple">
                  <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="apple">apple</label>
               </div>
               <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="canon">
                  <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="canon">canon</label>
               </div>
               <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="fils">
                  <label class="custom-control-label text-uppercase" for="fils">fils</label>
               </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of left side container containg filter  -->
      <!-- product section  -->
      <div class="col-sm-10 right ">
         <!-- Basic dropdown  sort  -->
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
               <div class="sort-sortBy float-right">
                  <!-- react-text: 325 -->Sort by :
                  <!-- /react-text -->
                  <span>Popularity</span>
                  <span class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-sort-down sort-downArrow"></i>
                  </span>
                  <ul class="sort-list">
                     <li>
                        <label class="sort-label ">
                           <input type="radio" value="new">
                           <!-- react-text: 332 -->What's New
                           <!-- /react-text -->
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="sort-label sort-selected">
                           <input type="radio" value="popularity">
                           <!-- react-text: 336 -->Popularity
                           <!-- /react-text -->
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="sort-label ">
                           <input type="radio" value="discount">
                           <!-- react-text: 340 -->Better Discount
                           <!-- /react-text -->
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="sort-label ">
                           <input type="radio" value="price_desc">
                           <!-- react-text: 344 -->Price: High to Low
                           <!-- /react-text -->
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="sort-label ">
                           <input type="radio" value="price_asc">
                           <!-- react-text: 348 -->Price: Low to High
                           <!-- /react-text -->
                        </label>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <label class="sort-label ">
                           <input type="radio" value="delivery_time">
                           <!-- react-text: 352 -->Faster Delivery
                           <!-- /react-text -->
                        </label>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- end of Basic dropdown : sort -->
         <!-- products section  -->
         <div class="row my-5"> ...
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: What's the problem exactly? The intended behavior you described is exactly how it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired by dividing the *container* into two vertical sections and the applying the css for the left side as

```
.left{
position :fixed;
}
```